# How to prevent running spark submit twice in case of failure in cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are running a batch process using spark and using `spark-submit` to submit our jobs with options

```
--deploy-mode cluster \
--master yarn-cluster \
```

We basically takes a csv files and do some processing on those files and create a parquet files from it. We are running multiple files in same spark submit command using a config file. Now lets say we have 10 files that we are processing and if the process fails on lets say file 6 Spark tries to re-run the process again and it will process all the files till file 6 and writes duplicate records for all those 5 files before failing. We are creating `Parquet` files and hence we don't have control over how spark names those files but it always create unique name.

Is there a way I can change the Spark property about not to re-execute a failed process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts` worked in my case I set its value to 1 like below in my spark submit command:

`--conf "spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1"`